# SocialTest - com.adobe.ane.social SocialUI could not be found

Tags: iphone, ios, air, adobe, flash-builder

I'm trying to run the sample SocialTest, but this error always appears:

```
VerifyError: Error # 1014: Class :: com.adobe.ane.social SocialUI could not be found.
```

The same applies to any other sample ANE, from gaming sdk...

FlashBuilder 4.7
Adobe AIR 3.6
Gaming SDK 1.0.2
iPhone 3gs 6.1.3
Simulator sdk 6.0

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the ANE to your package.

Project > Properties > Flex Build Packaging > (Your OS) > Native Extentions... Add...